# Why is John Marlott special in The Frankenstein Chronicles?

Tags: the-frankenstein-chronicles

In *The Frankenstein Chronicles*, why is Sean Bean's character, John Marlott special? Lord Harvey mentions this when John wakes up after the hanging in the hospital. And he seems to survive, unlike Lord Dipple who needs a special concoction. Will these be answered in the next series?

Comment: The show was cancelled :-(

Comment: When!? That's terrible. was so looking forward to an explanation!

Comment: the first story I saw was a few months back. I looked around for it and couldn't find it again, but did find a story on cinemaholic saying it had been picked up for season 3!!!

I'm really glad I looked again! I like that show, too, and was annoyed that it was ending. If I know a series on netflix or amazon prime has an abrupt ending, I don't watch it. 

So, good news :-)

Comment: thank you for letting me know. keeps me in good spirits. i too don't watch a show unless there is a continuity. like 'hinterland'. which seems to have stopped abruptly.